# Autocomplete textbox in google app engine with ajax

Tags: google-app-engine

Hello i am working with ajax in goolge app engine,
    i am trying to make autocomplete textbox.

```
    HTML CODE
    <input id="search_form">

    Ajax function is ,
    $('#search_form').autocomplete(/search)

    And class search is,

    class search(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = ['A','B','C', 'D']
        data = json.dumps(data)         
        self.response.out.write(data)
```

I am not familier about ajax , whats wrong with this code ?
   Is any thing is wrong with this code ?

Comment: interesting plugin, thanks! Your code is a snippet. I can't see anything obviously wrong. But there is not sufficient information. For example, does your search hander actually get called? If so, what does it attempt to return? If it does not get called, there is your problem right there. Or rather, you know it's on the browser side. What happens if you go directly to your handler with a browser? Does the data display? etc etc. Have you tried stepping through the code line by line with a debugger? Where did it not work as expected?

Comment: can you tell me how to do that ? I am new to google app engine

Comment: get a program like "pycharm" that allows you to step into your code line by line (debug mode) and watch what happens. Also make use of logging, at every point add a log entry and then examine the logs. The last entry will be where your program stopped. https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to

```
def get(self):
  data = ['A','B','C', 'D']
  data = json.dumps(data)         
  self.response.headers.add_header('content-type', 'application/json', charset='utf-8')
  return self.response.out.write(data)
```